# connect mac to ubuntu by ssh

Tags: ssh, openssh

for ssh connection

ssh -i id_rsa id@ip_address
in ip_address if I connect to my ubuntu from outside(not local ip) 
which ip_address should I put ??

i put my router ip address and

```
sssh connection to host ...... port 22: connection refuesed
```

Comment: Find you ubuntu ip `ip add show` and make sure you the ssh server on the ubuntu is installed

Comment: Also you want to make sure port forwarding is working first.

Comment: can you guys give me the link of related subject?